# Hyper-v replication gives timed out error

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

Due to a HDD space issue, I paused replication from our main server to replication/backup server. Both are running Win 2012R2.

I have now resolved the space issue on the destination server and Hyper-V is requiring me to 'resynchronize' a few VM's.

I have tried this, but on two of the VM's it is giving me a `Hyper-V failed to resynchronize changes for virtual machine '<VM NAME>': The operation timed out (0x00002EE2)` error in Event Viewer.

It then stops and starts from the beginning again and throws up this error again, and it just does this over and over...

Now I understand the 'timed out' error, but this is between two hosts that have a 1Gbps internet connection so I cannot see how that can be possible, certainly not if it is trying to say that the source/destination servers do not have enough bandwidth. I would accept that it times out for a different reason, but what could that be? The errors give no more info.

Is it possible to give the operation more time to try and complete? I assume that it is trying to resync the whole thing as it was disabled for around 2 weeks and cannot perform a simply 'replicate changes' and needs to do the whole thing.

It seems to get to 45% then throws that error, stops and tries again from 0%.

Any pointers on how to resolve would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this was to completely remove all replication and start again from scratch. To do so I simply removed replication on both sides, deleted all replicas on replica server and then initiated the replication on the main server again.

This was definitely not a connectivity issue, so I really do not know why I was getting the 'timeout' error.

Strange, but that's how I resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

It might be DNS or TCP/IP related error. Make sure that replica and source host can ping each other using ping or nslookup by DNS name, FQDN and IP. Here is some info (#3) - https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/advanced-troubleshooting-of-hyper-v-replica-part-1/